# Storing data of select query returning multiple returns for a specified column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a select query which returns multiple values.I have to store this in a variable and use it in the where clause of a cursor creation.What should be the type of my variable?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish. Do you know the where in clause? I think you don't need the variable

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should try not to store it, as combining the two queries into one will be easier and more efficient.

That aside, the type should be the same as the columns you are reading from.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier, you should combine the two queries (the query for CURSOR and the query to act as its WHERE clause) into a single query. However, if you must store data into variables before passing it to WHERE clause of CURSOR, you can define variable as follows:

Let's say your source table is TAB_SOURCE and you want to select columns COL1, COL2, and COL3 from it. Variable definition would be:

```
V_COL1 TAB_SOURCE.COL1%TYPE;
V_COL2 TAB_SOURCE.COL2%TYPE;
V_COL3 TAB_SOURCE.COL3%TYPE;
```

This way, you do not need to write data types explicitly while defining variables. DBMS automatically picks data type of source columns and assigns it to respective variables.